# Android Activity Stack

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

How to see if the next time I press the back (hardware) button, will take me on the screen. My question is basically: Is there a way to see the size of the `Activity` Stack (API level 7).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[boolean Activity.isTaskRoot();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isTaskRoot%28%29) Since: API Level 1

Return whether this activity is the root of a task.
The root is the first activity in a task.

Just don't do it in onCreate() as the calling activity may not have finish()ed itself yet.